# Error in sql query incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
insert into p_article_client_detail_current(article_id,sector_detail_id)
select article_id,2818
from ( select article_id from p_article_client_detail_current
       where sector_detail_id=239 and convert(varchar(11),feed_date,101) >= '12/07/2012'
)
```

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'**

what is wrong with this query , please help .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add a table name (for example `T`) as below:

```
insert into p_article_client_detail_current(article_id,sector_detail_id)
select article_id,2818
from ( select article_id from p_article_client_detail_current
       where sector_detail_id=239 and convert(varchar(11),feed_date,101) >= '12/07/2012'
) T
```

If you don't need nested query you can also to use this query:

```
insert into p_article_client_detail_current(article_id,sector_detail_id)
select article_id,2818
from p_article_client_detail_current
where sector_detail_id=239 
and convert(varchar(11),feed_date,101) >= '12/07/2012'
```

Comment: is the nested select unnecessary ?

Comment: It depends on your conditions. For me, you don't need it. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into p_article_client_detail_current(article_id,sector_detail_id)
select article_id,2818 from p_article_client_detail_current
where sector_detail_id=239 and convert(varchar(11),feed_date,101) >= '12/07/2012'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please insert a alias to the source from which you are inserting the data.

```
insert into p_article_client_detail_current(article_id,sector_detail_id)
select article_id,2818
from ( select article_id from p_article_client_detail_current
       where sector_detail_id=239 and convert(varchar(11),feed_date,101) >= '12/07/2012'
) as tablealias
```