# Insert Select data into Temporary Table in SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Question:** How to Insert Complicated select data Into temp Table  in sql 2012

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ppt.type) as Item_code,
ppt.type type,
...,
...,
...,
'11/02/19 09:51' Created_dt
from product psi
inner join  [DB1]..items ios on ios.icode=psi.icode
inner join [DB2]..types ppt on ppt.type=ios.type
```

I have Tried following **solution**

```
select * into #temptable from
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ppt.type) as Item_code,
ppt.type type,
...,
...,
...,
'11/02/19 09:51' Created_dt
from product psi
inner join  [DB1]..items ios on ios.icode=psi.icode
inner join [DB2]..types ppt on ppt.type=ios.type)
```

I got following **Error**

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

**When I am Normally running select statement i am getting expected data**

Comment: Created_dt, (comma should not be here)

Comment: in real query there is no comma i have edited check again

Comment: So, this is "fix my code, but I'm not going to show you my code"?

Comment: @Damien_The_unbeliever why

Comment: Well, so far someone's found one issue with the code, but it's with the "fake query" in the question, not the "real query" which you have actual problems with. There's an *obvious* extra `)` at the end of your second query that isn't present in the first, but who knows whether *that's* relevant to your actual problem...

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13816070/15498)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is correct as far as syntax goes:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temptable
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Ppt.Type) AS Item_Code,
           Ppt.Type AS Type,
           '11/02/19 09:51' AS Created_Dt
    FROM Product AS Psi
      INNER JOIN Db1..Items AS Ios ON Ios.Icode = Psi.Icode
      INNER JOIN Db2..Types AS Ppt ON Ppt.Type = Ios.Type );
```

Normally, you could capture the logic in a CTE and insert the CTE in your temp table.

```
USE SomeDB;
WITH CTE AS 
(

    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Ppt.Type) AS Item_Code,
            Ppt.Type AS Type,
            '11/02/19 09:51' AS Created_Dt
       FROM Product AS Psi
        INNER JOIN Db1..Items AS Ios ON Ios.Icode = Psi.Icode
        INNER JOIN Db2..Types AS Ppt ON Ppt.Type = Ios.Type )
)

INSERT INTO #T
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks its worked for me using common table expression

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are inserting data from an unnamed data source to a table.

```
select * into #temptable from
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ppt.type) as Item_code,
ppt.type type,
...,
...,
...,
'11/02/19 09:51' Created_dt
from product psi
inner join  [DB1]..items ios on ios.icode=psi.icode
inner join [DB2]..types ppt on ppt.type=ios.type) as tbl
```

Just go with this and your problem will be solved. I have just added a alias for the source you are inserting data.